# How to create a "Most Popular" & "Latest" TAB in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, css, html

On my gaming website, I upload videos to the website, which is on the homepage of the website.

The problem is, that I need to add a "Most Popular" tab & "Latest Videos" tab, where people can click and it shows my most popular videos.

I have attached a screenshot for reference, as it's the exact same functionality I need on my website.

[image]

Many thanks for any help, as this has been really stressing me out and frustrated, that something so simple as the "most popular" and "latest video" tab could become a major headache.

Cheers!

Comment: There not actually that simple.  Simple concepts, yes, but not simple execution.  For example, what determines most popular?  Most recent is easy, as you just query and order by date, that's sort of default.  You can record every time a post is viewed and then query based on those views.  If we're talking about a large volume then I'd consider perhaps storing the view counts in a separate table that's indexed properly.